# how to use range input in jquery mobile/

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

i am trying the range input for the 1st time. and whatever i do the theme applied in here:

[jquerymobile demo](https://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.2.0/docs/forms/slider/) doesn't stuck to my range input instead it just shows this lame style

[image: lame slider]

what is wrong? what am i doing wrong?!
here is my code

```
<div data-role="fieldcontain">
    <label for="slider">Input slider:</label>
    <input type="range" name="slider" id="slider" value="25" min="0" max="100" data-theme="a" data-track-theme="b" />
</div>
```

i am using :

```
jquery-1.11.2.js
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.js  
jquery.mobile-1.4.5.css
```

ps:screenshot is from android emulator using android 5.1.1

Comment: Could you put your code on jsFiddle or something similar?

Comment: Using your own code in jsFiddle seems to work: http://jsfiddle.net/ru5r6v5g/

Comment: Agreed, I also got your code work on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/4k6qfo0o/1/

Comment: I didn't use jsFiddle because the screenshot is from android emulator not a browser, actually it doesn't run in my browser as well. i will try to replace my jquery files.

Answer (score 0):

the solution was quite simple though i am not sure why

i just had to include the `jquery` before `jquery.mobile` ,that fixed it.